# how to record video by using Imgepicker.launchcamereAsync?

Tags: react-native

by using this command i am able to take picture but not able to take video. but i want to record both image and video. As soon as camera opens video button is getting disabled.

```
const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();
```

Comment: Please can you provide more information so we can help you. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for pointers.

Comment: i wanna access camera from my application ..but its allowing me only to take pictures its not allowing me to take video i want to take picture as well as video....function for record video ...........takeVideo = async () => {
    const status = await getPermission(Permissions.CAMERA,Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING,Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (status) {
      const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();

Comment: how to record video using reactnative